# How to retrieve data from the Spotify Access Token and how to verify the Access Token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, spotify

The Spotify Api has an option to [authorize users](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow), which I am currently using. When the authorization is complete, you'll receive an Authentication Token, which can be exchanged for an Access Token and Refresh Token. In my use case, the Access Token will be sent to the backend which requests user details using the `/me` call, after which an user will be created or logged in based on the Spotify data. The Spotify ID (in the response) will be used to create an user in my backend, so basically your Spotify ID is tied to an account in the backend.

The problem I'm currently facing is the following: in order to get the Spotify ID of the user, the backend has to make a `/me` call. This isn't ideal because Spotify has rate limits, which can easily be triggered this way. Normally when you authenticate using OAuth, you'll receive a JWT token which contains data, possibly an id. You can also verify if the JWT token has been tampered with using your public / private key. In Spotify's case, we do not receive a JWT token, but rather a general token. I can't seem to find out how to get any information from the token, I just don't know. I've tried Base64 decoding it and then AES (and DES and TripleDES and Rabbit and RC4) decrypting it using the public / private key, but no useful data is being retrieved. I cannot find any information on how to get any data out of it, no-one seems to have tried it yet..

Auth0 has a [Spotify integration](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/spotify), where they also (from what I could see) use the `/me` call in the backend. I suppose they are using a proxy or such to get around the rate limit, but this is not applicable for now. The problem I foresee is that any Spotify token from the internet could potentially log in to my backend, because I can't verify that the token has been created using my client ID...

In the hopes of some stranger on StackOverflow knowing the answer, or knowing how to help, I've listed all the public / private keys and responses I have retrieved (note: these are test keys, not my app's keys ):

```
Client ID: 6577d59d8dd643d5b2e53b25b0d5211e
Client Secret: c04640db6312400c9611229a81e65c6b
Authorization code: AQAGm98h91D9AsvavJXAL_V5DK-r6BtybDPbg7B31vZocO7TjOXqLQwhVSOmrHViXkippOPFjtrNjEjCQG6D0n1ImYbFXaTUNYGK4uIaeqqUdGne-KTZBE3MmBUP0iagpCY5HVjtTnty2FnL_JjD1a6omPAvSqTds1iexV6a
Access Token: BQAdbMy4Dhj0VCfnFS_VcEgjmMHBb9Sekjcal5F8T9HaXb7zIJjtsIRgjuzp4x3SGvAXgBw1NWdURSGGGHP5wPSU0Baqc9Zz4b5AvPGOX6aZy6w5c15GktTT_bvB-3wA3rfOqjYsrAGuzHuqxz0simNcYiQNiIyuhw
Refresh Token: AQApR35msEEcgq0pH7TWPXefcA8bHvc2rApA-mxRAuPo3QJVu5ksZMJMmh4jXy6USj2napzrZ9bJijVbkpZpgzPE8js-i-e9f7vVO0INnp-Q3P_gt3MIQ-4AbQ8eDBXORmw
```

**TL;DR:**

How to get data from the Spotify Access token, possibly using the client ID / client Secret?

Because I can't think (thats the question) of any way to verify the token, any Spotify token could be used to create an account in my backend, not just a token created with my client ID.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem if you try to use foreign access tokens in your own APIs. This type of access token is only designed for Spotify APIs and not for your own APIs to use.

The access token format is probably a reference token and the claims it uses can only be retrieved via OAuth introspection, which is an operation that I doubt you will have rights to perform.

**CORRECT APPROACH**

- You provide an Authorization Server (AS), such as Auth0
- Users can login in multiple ways, one of which is Spotify
- To sign a user in, your app first redirects to your AS, which then redirects to Spotify, where the user authenticates
- Spotify issues tokens to your AS, which then issues its own tokens to your UI
- Your UI sends tokens to your API, and the API is in full control of dealing with the token, and any identifiers / claims / scopes within it

This might sound complicated, but all of the security details are externalised from your UIs and APIs, so it leads to simple code. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) has further details on the pattern.

Comment: Yes that was what I was thinking too, they probably have their own format which isn't allowed to be read by outsiders. In my use case, everything evolves around the Spotify account, so I therefore would not like to have another way of logging in. In the steps you mentioned, any token (not created by my client id) could send a valid token of the user from the "UI" to the server, which is unfortunate. I do understand, I just wish there was another way, like verifying the token or an endpoint of Spotify to verify it..

Comment: The standard way to issue access tokens is that a client is given an audience for access tokens, such as 'api.mycompany.com', and you also control the token signing key. This means any malicious client would not have the right tokens, so would get a 401 when calling your API. Of course these guarantees are missing if you use Spotify access tokens to call your own APIs.

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm used to having a JWT token with an audience, or any option to verify the token has been created with a private key (and can be verified using the public key). These are indeed missing, I'd hope someone out there knows some more specific information about the Spotify token (maybe it does have a structure), I don't want to change the login method.